# Undefined variable in view

Tags: cakephp, view

I am having an issue setting variables in the controller and showing it at the view.

my codes are as follow:
In my view (pages/anything.ctp):

```
<?php echo $anything; ?>
```

In my controller (pagesController.php):

```
public function anything() {
        $a = "asdasdas";
        $this->set('anything', $a);
}
```

I am new to Cake, and I've done quite a number of search in google and stack. Still no luck.

I'd be grateful if anybody could help, or if anyone already asked this question before please provide a link that would be best.

Comment: what error you are receiving ? Is debug mode on ?

Answer (score 0):

First read  the following article [Controller actions in CakePHP CookBook](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#controller-actions)

When you use controller methods with requestAction(), you will often want to return data that isn’t a string. If you have controller methods that are used for normal web requests + requestAction, you should check the request type before returning:

```
class RecipesController extends AppController {
    public function popular() {
        $popular = $this->Recipe->popular();
        if (!empty($this->request->params['requested'])) {
            return $popular;
        }
        $this->set('popular', $popular);
    }
}
```

The above controller action is an example of how a method can be used with `requestAction()` and normal requests. Returning array data to a non-requestAction request will cause errors and should be avoided. See the section on `requestAction()` for more tips on using `requestAction()`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public function anything() {
    $a = "asdasdas";
    $this->set(compact('a'));
}

<?php echo $a; ?>
```